# include column with 0/1 to the intercept in a linear fixed model

Tags: r, matrix, linear-regression

Let's assume that I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
|--------------|-----------|-----------|-------|-----|-----------|
|coffeeshop_id | americano | capuccino | latte | tea | mean_price|
|--------------|-----------|-----------|-------|-----|-----------|
|15476         |1          | 0         | 0     | 1   | 2.35      |
|--------------|-----------|-----------|-------|-----|-----------|
|13466         |0          | 1         | 0     | 1   | 2.45      |
|--------------|-----------|-----------|-------|-----|-----------|
```

I want to build a linear regression and to make americano as a reference in the intercept.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `relevel` to set a new reference level for fitting a model.

```
# create some data
set.seed(1)
x <- factor(sample(letters[1:3], size=20, replace=T))
y <- rnorm(20)
my.df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)

# model fitted with "a" as the reference level
summary(lm(y~x, data=my.df))

# set "b" as the reference level
my.df$x <- relevel(my.df$x, ref='b')
summary(lm(y~x, data=my.df))
```

Comment: will it calculate a mean price over each observation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Do you mean a mean per observation, a mean over all observations, or a mean per level of the factor?

Comment: a mean per observation

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something, but a mean per observation sounds to me like taking the mean of a single value.